# Jasmine fails to execute but Karma works fine with DESCRIBE

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Here is my spec.ts file that I try to run on Jasmine:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm, FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
import { TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './myWebApp.component';

describe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));
```

and it fails with following error in Chrome console:

```
Error: TypeError: require is not a function
    Evaluating https://npmcdn.com/@angular/forms@2.4.0/index.js
    Error loading https://npmcdn.com/@angular/forms@2.4.0/index.js as "@angular/forms" from https://run.plnkr.co/yr4o5FIKlm3GQRaj/myWebApp.component.spec.ts
```

Everything works fine on Karma.
Now when I comment

```
// imports: [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
```

Then it at least start working but fail testing. Is there anything I need to adjust in Jasmine to avoid the error above and execute the tests?

Comment: If you run it in Karma, why does the error say `run.plnkr.co`?

Comment: Sorry for confusion. It fails in Plunker. When I run it in Visual Studio Code with Karma everything works fine

Comment: Well, Karma does bundling for you, while you should take care of how the files are transpiled in Plunker by yourself. SystemJS should be configured the right way. If you're interested in making it work in Plunker, consider posting http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve